# How to get the System HostName of kubernetes deployment inside pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In kubernetes we can use environment variable to pass hostIP using

```
 env:
    - name: NODE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

So similarly how get hostName instead of HostIP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
env:
- name: MY_NODE_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: spec.nodeName
```

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api

Comment: Will it give a fully qualified name? Or what will be the format?

Comment: Depends on how your cluster was setup. It'll be the same format you get from `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: Thanks, my setup is we have 3 nodes with each node having a single pod and each node deployed in a different JVM. Now this Yaml would be configured and run from kubernetes Master. Even in that case when we read this env variable inside a pod, it would give the hostName/systemName where that particular node runs right?

Comment: Where that particular POD runs

Comment: @EdwardRosinzonsky If I want to get the first 5 characters of "sepc.nodeName" , is there a way to do it. We have an app running from a thirdparty that can take only 5 chars. NodeName or POD ID we can use. But I don't know how to extract few characters and assign it to a "env" variable.

Comment: @PraveenMak, the hostname will be in the environment variable MY_NODE_NAME. Inside the pod, you can get the first 5 characters with `${MY_NODE_NAME:0:5}`, or (if you don't have bash) `$(echo $MY_NODE_NAME | cut -c1-5)`

Comment: Thanks Edward, I am aware of the bash shortcuts. Like I said , its a third-party. I cannot modify their image. I want to pass it from Kubernetes yaml as environment.

Comment: You don't need to modify the image, just the command. If you control the manifest, you can change the command.

Comment: Well, not exactly. If we add/change the "command"  in manifest, that overwrites the actual application entrypoint.

Comment: `command: [ '/bin/bash', '-c', 'MY_NODE_NAME=${MY_NODE_NAME:0:5}; old_command' ]`

Answer (score 2):

That should be, as already answered, `spec.nodeName`.

What I also wanted to mention, there is a limited number of fields you can use. Check  [Capabilities of the Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api).

```
Information available via fieldRef:
metadata.name 
metadata.namespace
metadata.uid 
metadata.labels['<KEY>']
metadata.annotations['<KEY>'] 

In addition, the following information is available through downwardAPI volume fieldRef:    
metadata.labels
metadata.annotations 

The following information is available through environment variables:    
status.podIP - the pod's IP address
spec.serviceAccountName 
spec.nodeName - the node's name, available since v1.4.0-alpha.3
status.hostIP - the node's IP, available since v1.7.0-alpha.1
```

Comment: Will it give a fully qualified name? Or what will be the format?